# Export PDF error, An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, dictionary

i am trying to export pdf from database, but i have this problem

> An item with the same key has already been added

in last row -  `zip.AddFile(str, "")`;

So how to solve this problem? Below are the codes:

```
public static void generateRespondentReport(string startDate, string endDate)
{
    List<string> inpatientFileList = generateRespondentReportByQuestionSet(1, startDate, endDate);
    List<string> outpatientFileList = generateRespondentReportByQuestionSet(2, startDate, endDate);
    List<string> visitorFileList = generateRespondentReportByQuestionSet(3, startDate, endDate);

    // timestamp           
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string FileName = "RespondentReport_" + now.Day + now.ToString("MMM") + now.Year + "_" + string.Format("{0:hh-mm-sstt}", now) + ".zip";
    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Clear();
    response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");

    // add into zipfile
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
    foreach (string str in inpatientFileList)
    {
        zip.AddFile(str, "");
    }
    foreach (string str in outpatientFileList)
    {
        zip.AddFile(str, "");
    }
    foreach (string str in visitorFileList)
    {
        zip.AddFile(str, "");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding the file, first check that the file doesn't already exist in the zip...

```
        foreach (string str in <X>)
        {
            var nameCount = zip.Count(entry => entry.FileName == str);
            if (nameCount>0)
            {
                zip.AddFile(str + string.Format("({0})",nameCount), "");
            }
            else
            {
                zip.AddFile(str, "");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you using zipDotNet? If so, I'd extend the class with a new "AddFile" method that can figure out filename collisions. I'll write one up if so.

Comment: Does <X> represent my FileList? Then i do this method three times?

Comment: Yes, It represent the FileList. Yes, Or you could join all the list together, or create a helper function. I try creating an Extension of FileList, but it cannot be extend :\

Comment: i did this method three times, but it shows the same error. is there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Most likely the path variable (AddFile's second var) is empty and could be throwing the error. Less likely it could be generateRespondentReportByQuestionSet or code that follows the foreach loops. Are these files in memory?

Comment: so how can i check these files in memory? but it works in the other computer, but doesn't work in my computer.